# Bug in debugging

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform project where it starts  from the code in Program.cs, in which the first form (Login) to be loaded as described:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
```

now I have made some changes in Login form which is not being applied while debugging. I decided to create a new form called frmLogin and paste all the UI from Login form and change the loading page from Login to frmLogin

```
        Application.Run(new frmLogin());
```

but still my old Login form is being loaded everytime I run the program.

is there any solution to this.

Comment: Clean and rebuild.

Comment: There is no way to know what is going on without good [MCVE]. Usually such errors disappear on rebuild, but if not - roll back your code to previous version with whatever source control system you use (with git - "git stash") and start over. Than when you have should be able to [edit] post with exact minimal sample.

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding signature and "thank you" text to posts.

Comment: If you have a file `App.xaml` check the `StartupUri`.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild worked